# ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

PreferenceManager is deprecated and I added

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01'
```

in build.gradle but it shows ERROR: Failed to resolve: `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01` why?

Comment: Are all your dependencies using AndroidX and not support library?

Comment: Yes.All of my dependencies are using AndroidX.